# Secure data transfer from remote MongoDB instance

Tags: mongodb, security, networking

I have a production MongoDB instance on my server. Sometimes I want to download some data from it to my PC for some processing. How can I do it in a secure and simple way?

I see 3 ways.

1) Create Mongo instance on my PC, set up Mongo replication, replicate and use my local Mongo. Looks like production MongoDB will be exposed to internet which means increased vulnerability.

2) Write script or code that will connect to remote Mongo and download data. Actually the same idea, but I dont know whether its better in terms of security, now we can connect via ssh for example.

3) Write code that sends Mongo data to my PC from that side. A bigger job: dataSender and dataReceiver. But I dont need to expose my production instance to internet.

The problem is that I have a very basic understanding of network security and I just have started using MongoDB. So may be I am just inventing a bycycle here :) Please advice me which way is better.

Comment: If you do not want to expose your server to internet then the only way is to do a mongoexport and connect to your production machine using a drive, download the json file and mongoimport it into your machine.

Comment: vmr, in in any case I have to connect via internet. The question is  how can I orhanize it. Is it safe to establish a replication via internet?